# Apple appstore guidelines - Loading progression

Tags: ios, loading, progress, requirements

I'm trying to figure out if it is a requirement for apps submitted to the iOS appstore to show the progression of data being down/loaded (by means of a progress bar or something similar) or if simply letting the user know that loading is in progress is sufficient. My app generally only loads for 2 seconds so i figure showing a progress bar is not really necessary but if it is a requirement then obviously i have no choice. Here's hoping someone can enlighten me :)

Comment: No it's not mandatory but I think it is a pretty good practice to notify the user.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's an Apple tech support question and isn't related to coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a two second load (and you can ensure that that's pretty much what it will ever be on all devices supported) I think you should be perfectly fine.  Think of Apple reviewers as the most impatient user you have ever encountered.  If you normal user is watching you app load and thinking "Is it frozen or still loading something?" the Apple reviewer is going to say it's frozen and close your app and start the write-up saying it froze.

For short activities I see no need for a progress view (I do them anyway, but that's just my preference).  For long activities make sure to show some progress indication other than the beachball of death activity indicator.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, i'm leaning towards showing a progression bar anyways like yourself. But its good to know what is generally expected in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a mistake to assume that Apple has "requirements" for UI elements. The UI Guidelines are just that - recommendations on how your app should behave when there's *no better reason to behave otherwise.* Every app writer should develop a user interface which works best for his app and his users.  If you don't have a reason to break the guidelines, then follow the guidelines.  If you do have a reason, and it's worth it to the user to do it your way instead of the Apple way, then do it your way.

For this particular purpose, though, I like the progress view.  The reasoning being: suppose the load fails.  A progress bar with no movement indicates failure, but a message saying "loading..." that continues to sit will make the user feel the app is still gainfully employed.

Comment: Yes this is also my main concern, that in case the load may fail not giving any indication of progression might cause unnecessary confusion.